# Using require() later in code and should one handle any exceptions thrown thereby

Tags: kotlin, exception, require

I have a kotlin class with a method

```
loadElements(e: Iterable<Int>) {
}
```

This then constructs a new copy of that `Iterable` as an `ArrayList<Int>` within the object.

It is a requirement that all the elements in that `ArrayList<Int>` be non-negative. It is considered a breach of contract by the caller if that is not met. I've been led to believe that "breach of contract" is something to be tested by `require()`, whereas `check()` is for testing logic internal to that method. Is this correct ?

All the examples I have seen, have the `require()` as the very first lines of code within the method. Is it, however, acceptable to run `require()` in a loop, like this ?

```
    public fun loadElements(e: Iterable<Int>) {
        elementArray.clear()
        e.forEach {
            require(it>=0)
            elementArray.add(it)
            moduleCount += it
        }
        if (elementCount %2 == 1)
            elementArray.add(0)
        check(elementCount %2 == 0)
        computeInternalSizes()
    }
```

Thing is, this means that part of the object's internals may already be set-up by the time the `require()` breach is detected: i.e., `moduleCount` will be wrong and `computeInternalSizes()` will never get called.

Now, of course I could just use a separate pass, with the first one checking for the `require()` condition, and then doing all the real work thereafter. This would mean that if the input came in as a `Sequence<Int>`, it would be forced to be terminal and multi-iterable.

If the `require()` throws, I would like to assume that the program cannot continue because a design error has occurred somewhere. However, if someone traps the resultant exception, and continues, I will end-up with an incoherent object state.

What is best practice for handling conditions where incoming parameter breaches won't be noticed until some significant unrewindable work has been done ?

I tried using a separate pass for checking for non-negativity. This worked perfectly well but, given that it could be coming from a Sequence or similar, I don't want to have to build the whole sequence, and then traverse that sequence again.

I tried using check(). This works, but it just shows up as an inconsistency in object state, rather than flagging up the incoming parameter validation, which is making a breach of contract look like an internal design fault, and just delaying the inevitable.

I've tried putting try/catch/finally all over the place, but this is an excessive amount of code for such a simple thing.

I'm not even sure if a program *should* attempt recovery if a require() fails.

Answer (score 0):

In general you avoid situations like this, by reducing the scope of mutability in your code.

The difference between `require` and `check` is mostly a convention. They throw different Exceptions, namely `IllegalArgumentException` and `IllegalStateException` respectively. As the type of the Exceptions suggest, former is suited for validating the (user) input to a method whereas the latter is designed to check intermediate states during the runtime.
Exceptions in Kotlin should be handled as such, being an *Exception* that should not occur regularly. See also the [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/exceptions.html#checked-exceptions) why there are no checked exceptions in Kotlin.

You did not write the name of your surrounding Kotlin class, thus I'll call it `Foo` for the time being.
Rather than providing a function on `Foo`, that mutates the internal state of `Foo`, you could create new instances of `Foo` based on the `Iterable<Int> / Sequence<Int>`. This way, you only ever have an `Foo` object when its in a valid state.

```kotlin
private class Foo(source: Iterable<Int>) {

    private val elementArray = ArrayList<Int>()
    private val moduleCount: Int

    init {
        var internalCount = 0

        for (count in source) {
            require(count > 0)

            elementArray.add(count)
            internalCount += count
        }

        moduleCount = internalCount

        if (elementArray.size % 2 == 1) {
            elementArray.add(0)
        }

        check(elementArray.size % 2 == 0)
        // ...
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you want / need to keep the interface as described in your question but also avoid the invalid state, you could make use of an intermediate copy.
As you're copying the incoming `Iterable<Int> / Sequence<Int>` into an `ArrayList<Int>` I assume you're not working with very large collections.

```kotlin
private class Foo(source: Iterable<Int>) {

    private val elementArray = ArrayList<Int>()
    private var moduleCount = 0

    public fun loadElements(source: Iterable<Int>) {
        val internalCopy = ArrayList<Int>()
        for (count in source) {
            require(count >= 0)
            internalCopy.add(count)
        }

        elementArray.clear()
        for (count in internalCopy) {
            elementArray.add(count)
            moduleCount += count
        }
        
        if (elementArray.size % 2 == 1) {
            elementArray.add(0)
        }
        check(elementArray.size % 2 == 0)
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, immutability is usually the way to go. I should have given the full class definition. It is a derived class of View, with loadElements() being of a similar use-case to setText() in a TextView. It is for displaying one-dimensional barcodes